# Robocopy GUI log shows 1 skipped but none were

Tags: robocopy

I copied 145 mb with Robocopy GUI. Source and Destination show exact same properties (# of files, directories, and size). The log file shows 100% at the end of every line. I assume that means everything copied correctly. But the log summary shows 1 skipped (file or directory). So what's up with the summary showing a something skipped?

Comment: The log (screen output) itself should show you which file or directory was skipped.

Comment: Could it be the parent folder that already existed at the destination?